# How to solve this JS SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and I'm trying some stuff to learn it. Here I'm stuck with this SyntaxError. I know it's supposed to point to an identifier starting with a digit, but there's none... So where's the problem ? Could you please help me ?

```
var mouse = document.getElementById('square');
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
div.onmouseover = function() {
  var posL = 275;
  var posV = 275;
  var time = setInterval(move, 2);
  function move() {
    if ((posL==275)&&(posV==275)){
      box.style.left = 275px;
      box.style.top = 0px;
      posV = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `275px` is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is trying to parse `275px` and `0px` as code. It recognizes numbers like `275` as a numerical value but is puzzled by the `px` attached to it. You should use strings here, in JS they are delimited with `'` or `"`.

Corrected code:

```
var mouse = document.getElementById('square');
//SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
div.onmouseover = function() {
  var posL = 275;
  var posV = 275;
  var time = setInterval(move, 2);
  function move() {
    if ((posL==275)&&(posV==275)){
      box.style.left = '275px';
      box.style.top = '0px';
      posV = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I thought that the SyntaxError was linked to the code line above...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the qoutes:

```
 box.style.left = "275px";
 box.style.top = "0px";
```

Also, in `div.onmouseover` you need to define `div` first or you probably mean `mouse.onmouseover`